# Spring Batch Exit Job If Step Fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want a job to exit if a step within the job fails. I'm using Spring Batch annotation and not XML.

I have a job step defined below:

```
@Bean(name = "callM204Step")
    public Step callM204Step(StepBuilderFactory stepFactory, CallM204ProgramTasklet task) {
        return stepFactory.get("callM204Step") //
                .tasklet(task) //
                .allowStartIfComplete(true) //
                .build();
    }
```

If this step fails, how can I exit the job?

Comment: By default, if the step fails, the job will fail too.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks. Something in my configuration is preventing this. I'll have to look into this.

Comment: In this case, please share your full job configuration to see what could go wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wasn't aware that if a step fails the job also fails. Thank you.